# Get nested static classes names programatically and access a method

Tags: c#

I have a nested class structure like this one

```
public static class Animals{


    private static class Dolphins
    {
        public static int GetAge()
        {

        }
    }

    private static class Cats
    {
        public static int GetAge()
        {

        }
    }

    private static class Dogs
    {
        public static int GetAge()
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Is it possible to get sub-classes names programatically in a for loop, so I can call GetAge() method for all of them? Like this (pseudocode):

```
foreach(subclass in Animals)
{
   subclass.GetAge()
}
```

I tried via reflection but I was able to get descendant classes of a base, not nested classes in a static base like above.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Should these not be instances instead of static classes? It seems strange to me that a static class has an "Age".

Comment: Make a Interface 'IAge' , let all sub class implement it, and use relfaction found out all subclass form 'IAge' and invoke GetAge()

Comment: In addition to Johns comment. This exact thing would be really easy just using non-static classes. To have similar functionality to using static, you should use a [singleton pattern](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton). Since by default `static` classes in C# aren't thread safe, you don't need to go overboard but if necessary, you have the possibility to make the singleton threadsafe if you use this pattern instead of a `static` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cs
foreach(var type in typeof(Animals).GetNestedTypes(
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    var method = type.GetMethod("GetAge", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
        null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
    if (method != null)
    {
        int age = (int)method.Invoke(null, null);
        Console.WriteLine(age);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code answers the question, I feel like providing additional context as to how and why it does so would improve the answer greatly and add to it's long term value

Comment: @Marc Gravell thanks a lot, pointed me exactly to what I was looking for and works great. Nice day!

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to get [Nested Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getnestedtypes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetNestedTypes_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_).

> GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags)
>
> When overridden in a derived class, searches for the types nested in the current Type, using the specified binding constraints.

Then use the [Static Binding Flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netframework-4.8).

> Specifies flags that control binding and the way in which the search for members and types is conducted by reflection.

---

> Static - Specifies that static members are to be included in the search.

Comment: It would be great if you could add some example code in your answer to show how to use the linked documentation to solve such a problem

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, using interface will be more fitting. But anyway, here is a one line implementation of what you asked:

```
typeof(Animals).GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).ToList()
  .ForEach(t => /*do something with the returned value*/t.GetMethod("GetAge", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)?.Invoke(null, null));
```

Comment: `ToList().ForEach(...)` on a perfectly good array is ... well, OK it'll work, but - why not just `foreach`?

Comment: I confuse about 'private' static class , Is it can be invoke by other class ? (out of animals scope)

Comment: @MarcGravell the ForEach extension is not available for arrays

Comment: @TimChang in normal code, you can't. But using reflection, you can.

Comment: @SohaibJundi I didn't say `ForEach` - I said `foreach`; and `foreach` is *absolutely* available for arrays. There are exactly zero reasons to **ever** use the `ForEeach` method on lists. There are no scenarios where it does anything *better* than regular `foreach`, and lots of scenarios where it makes things *much worse*. If I can offer one piece of advice: stop using `List<T>.ForEach`

Comment: @MarcGravell looks like I misunderstood you, you are absolutely right. I know, performance wise, this much is worse, but I used it just for being compact.